# Python Azure Function service bus topic complete after process

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I wrote a azure function in python on Service bus topic, it works well but the issue is its not marking message as completed after finish.. the message process processed several time untill the count reached.. need to know how to mark message as complete here is my code.

```
def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    
    try:
        message_content_type = message.content_type
        req_body = message.get_body().decode("utf-8")
        
        logging.info(req_body)
        response = obj_engine.extract_payload_message(req_body)

        connection_str = os.environ["idpdev_SERVICEBUS"];
        ocr_topic_name = os.environ["idpdev_topic"]
        servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_str, logging_enable=True)
        with servicebus_client:
            sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=sender_topic_name)
            with sender:
                send_message = ServiceBusMessage(json.dumps(response))
                sender.send_messages(send_message)                
                
    except ValueError:
        pass




can someone please help to know what setting i am missing to add.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you need to enable auto completion by setting `autoComplete` to `true` using [the configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration):

> Must be true for non-C# functions, which means that the trigger should either automatically call complete after processing, or the function code manually calls complete.
>
> When set to true, the trigger completes the message automatically if the function execution completes successfully, and abandons the message otherwise.
>
> Exceptions in the function results in the runtime calls abandonAsync in the background. If no exception occurs, then completeAsync is called in the background. This property is available only in Azure Functions 2.x and higher.

The configuration can be found in the `function.json` file, make sure the property is available and set to true, see the example below:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "entryPoint": "main",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "mytopic",
      "subscriptionName": "mysubscription",
      "connection": "",
      "autoComplete": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```